# Except Operation in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Good day!

What is the best way to perform the `EXCEPT` SQL operation using Laravel's query builder?

I guess I could do this at the application layer using PHP's array_diff or perform a raw SQL query to the database but I am wondering if there is a more *native* way of handling this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QueryBuilder api has `whereIn/whereNotIn` i.e., (in and not in semantics in SQL), functions that I can use to achieve the effect.